# Removing one of the two installed Jupyters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, homebrew

In my system, by mistake, a second Jupyter is now installed.

```
which -a jupyter:
    /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter  #latest jupyter which should be removed
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter #previous working jupyter
```

While the second one,"`/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter`" is what I was working with, the first one,"`/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter`" does not work because of its wrong python path and uninstalled packages.

I have tried to remove this jupyter by `brew uninstall jupyter,` but it didn't work because of this error `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyter.`

As I have numerous packages and libraries on the second jupyter.
Thus, I am not willing to reinstall jupyter from scratch.
Calling `Jupyer notebook` at the moment calls the first path. Do you have any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like you have a python that was installed by homebrew. Do you have a `python` and `pip` in `/opt/homebrew/bin/`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes. I have `pip3` and `python3.9` and `python3` in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have a python that was installed through `brew`, you should be able to do

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 uninstall jupyter
```

Note that the underlying issue seems to be that your `PATH` is not set such that the anaconda bin folder takes precedence over the `homebrew/bin` folder, which you might or might not want to adress. You could also consider uninstalling the homebrew python version with

```
brew uninstall python
```

Comment: I have tried `/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 uninstall jupyter` and got the message that `WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed.` But I still can find `jupyter` in `/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter`.

Comment: I just did `rm /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter` not sure how it got there and pip and brew wanted to pretend they didn't know who did it!

Answer (score 0):

/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 uninstall jupyter_core

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).